# Pushview on didselectrowatindexpath in storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard, pushviewcontroller, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a tableview added as a subview in one of the viewcontrollers in storyboard. It has 6 sections each having one row. On selecting each row a new viewcontroller should open. There are 6 such different viewcontrollers for that. I dont know how to achieve this in storyboard. Is there any way to bind this via storyboard or i have to do this manually. Any help will be accepted.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `performSegueWithIdentifier` method when you take view controllers in story board.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    if (indexPath.section==0) {

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"first" sender:nil];

    }
    if (indexPath.section==1) {

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"second" sender:nil];

    }
    if (indexPath.section==2) {

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"third" sender:nil];

    }
    if (indexPath.section==3)
    {

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"fourth" sender:nil];

    }


}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"first"])
    {
        friendsViewController=[segue destinationViewController];

    }
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"second"])
    {
         secondViewController=[segue destinationViewController];

    }
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"third"])
    {
        thirdViewController=[segue destinationViewController];

    }
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"fourth"])
    {
        fourthViewController=[segue destinationViewController];



    }
}
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your tableview with static cells, and all of them are placed on storyboard, then you can easily drag with `ctrl` button and left mouse button from every cell to needed ViewController to create the segue.

Comment: yes i have with static cells, and have already tried the way you are saying, but problem i am facing is that i have taken viewcontroller and not a tableviewcontroller. so it is showing 'Static cells are only valid when embeded within uitableviewcontroller' error